# How to format text data by awk

Tags: awk

The text data:

```
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept;java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept;java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept;java.net.ServerSocket.accept;sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop;sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run;java.lang.Thread.run  40
sun.misc.Unsafe.park;java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos;java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos;java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take;java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take;java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take;java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask;java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run;java.lang.Thread.run  20
java.lang.Object.wait;sun.misc.GC$Daemon.run  20
java.lang.Object.wait;java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove;sun.rmi.transport.DGCClient$EndpointEntry$RenewCleanThread.run;java.lang.Thread.run  20
java.lang.Object.wait;java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove;java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove;sun.rmi.transport.ObjectTable$Reaper.run;java.lang.Thread.run  20
java.lang.Object.wait;java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove;java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove;java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run  20
java.lang.Object.wait;java.lang.Object.wait;java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run  20
java.lang.Object.wait;com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteServer.start;org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteMavenServer.main  20
sun.misc.Unsafe.park;java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos;java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill;java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer;java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll;java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask;java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run;java.lang.Thread.run  15
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0;java.net.SocketInputStream.read;java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill;java.io.BufferedInputStream.read;java.io.FilterInputStream.read;sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages;sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0;sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run;java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask;java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run;java.lang.Thread.run  4
```

For example line one

```
java.lang.Thread.run;sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run;sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop;java.net.ServerSocket.accept;java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept;java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept;java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept 40
```

How to format the file to like example line one?

Comment: Is your intension to reverse the order of all the strings in the first column using the separator `;`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to get the field you like.  Here is some to get you started.

```
awk -F"[; .]" -v OFS=. 'NR==1 {print $29,$30,$31,$32";"$17,$18,$19,$20,$21}'
java.lang.Thread.run;sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop
```

Comment: if i don't know the files number

Comment: @fuyou001 If you run this: `awk -F"[; .]" 'NR==1 {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print i,$i}'` you get the position number.  If that changes, you have another story.  You does not tell what rules should be used one every line to get there.